# CUPS does not show me printers except with brave browser

Tags: arch-linux, cups, openrc

Suddenly, since yesterday CUPS has not shown me printers in any application except brave browser (see screenshots above).

[image]
[image]

I use Archlinux with OpenRC (artoo way). Before yesterday, I have no problems with printing. I'm in `lp` group and `cupsd` service is started.

Comment: I suspect is this [issue](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS/Troubleshooting#Printers_are_not_present_in_the_print_dialog_for_GTK3_applications)

Comment: If installing [`gtk3-print-backends`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=gtk3-print-backends) fixes your problem, you should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that GTK3 applications need a package for using printing system: [`gtk3-print-backends`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=gtk3-print-backends). Installing this package solves the problem